# eabihf What is hf standing for?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to understand cross compilation. Many cross compilers mention gnueabihf. I was able to understand what EABI stands for, but I couldn't find anything about the hf suffix. What does it mean?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it stands for 'hard-float'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hf` means Hard Float.
When you use this flag, during compilation, your compiler will compile your program so that it will use the `Floating Point Unit` once launched.
Your program will run faster but only if you use floating points!
Be carreful not to use this flag if your CPU doesn't support it, or it will not start.

EDIT:
Also, if you use `Soft Float` it will compute every floats "softwarely".

Comment: No, hard-float/soft-float is purely an ABI for whether floating-point arguments are passed in FPU registers or general-purpose registers. Soft-float code can perfectly well use an FPU if it exists (the necessary register-shuffling does tend to give a moderate performance hit vs. hard-float), but _also_ allows falling back to emulation. For example, Android uses the soft-float ABI for native code, but plenty of that _depends_ on hardware FPU performance (NEON).